# Returning resources with different types for rails Restful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am working on implementing a search endpoint with ruby based on a json request sent from the client which should have the form GET /workspace/:id/searches? filter[query]=Old&filter[type]=ct:Tag,User,WokringArea&items=5
The controller looks like this

```
class SearchesController < ApiV3Controller
    load_and_authorize_resource :workspace, class: "Company"
    load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :working_area, through: :workspace

    def index
      keyword = filtered_params[:query].delete("\000")
      keyword = '%' + keyword + '%'
      if filtered_params[:type].include?('User')
        @users = @workspace.users.where("LOWER(username) LIKE LOWER(?)", keyword)
      end
      if filtered_params[:type].include?('WorkingArea')
        @working_areas = @workspace.working_areas.where("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)", keyword)
      end
      @resources = @working_areas

      respond_json(@resources)
    end

    private

    def filtered_params
      params.require(:filter).permit(:query, :type)
    end

    def ability_klasses
      [WorkspaceAbility, UserWorkspaceAbility, WorkingAreaAbility]
    end
  end
```

respond_json returns the resources with a json format and it looks like this

```
def respond_json(records, status = :ok)
if records.try(:errors).present?
  render json: {
    errors: records.errors.map do |pointer, error|
      {
        status: :unprocessable_entity,
        source: { pointer: pointer },
        title: error
      }
    end
  }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  return
elsif records.respond_to?(:to_ary)
  @pagy, records = pagy(records)
end

options = {
  include: params[:include],
  permissions: permissions,
  current_ability: current_ability,
  meta: meta_infos
}

render json: ApplicationRecord.serialize_fast_apijson(records, options), status: status
```

end

Now the issue is the response is supposed to look like this:

```
{
data: [
    {
        id: 32112,
        type: 'WorkingArea'
        attributes: {}
    },
    {
        id: 33321,
        type: 'User',
        attributes: {}
    },
    {
        id: 33221,
        type: 'Tag'
        attributes: {}
    }
```

How can I make my code support responding with resources that have different types?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a model, not in your database, that is based on the results from the API. Then you include some of the ActiveModel modules for more features.

```
# app/models/workspace_result.rb
class WorkspaceResult
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  attr_accessor(
    :id,
    :type,
    :attributes
  )

  def initialize(attributes={})
    filtered_attributes = attributes.select { |k,v| self.class.attribute_method?(k.to_sym) }
    super(filtered_attributes)
  end

  def self.from_json(json)
    attrs = JSON.parse(json).deep_transform_keys { |k| k.to_s.underscore }
    self.new(attrs)
  end
end
```

Then in your API results you can do something like:

```
results = []
response.body["data"].each do |result|
  results << WorkspaceArea.from_json(result)
end
```

You can also define instance methods on this model, etc.